# Looking for a math expression to fit these series of inputs/graphs

Tags: graphing-functions

I require a math formula that lets me move smoothly between these graphs:

[image]

It must always intersect x=0 and x=1 as seen, and its peak must always be at 1. It can be a parametric equation. How might I generate something like this.

For example that middle graph might be equal to $y=-\left(2x-1\right)^{2}+1$

But that equation needs to somehow be modified to produce those other graphs.

Its almost like its interpolating between these 3 graphs:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2cofwiga9k

Comment: An attempt might be 
$$ \sin(\pi x^{p}) $$

I like the results for 0<p<1

Comment: sorry your link seems corrupted

Comment: ok..its not a bad approximation..but its not really perfect. Here you can slide it here, you can see the issues:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dkkxhft1dn

Comment: @Jaume Oliver Lafont Nice find, well done.

Comment: $$x^{p}(1-x)^{1-p}$$ has the right symmetry but fails the scaling... Dividing it by the maximum value should work.

Comment: Jaume Oliver..almost there! Perhaps the dividing parameter/scaling value can be a function of p somehow

Comment: Certainly. It is $$p^p(1-p)^{1-p}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fit is given by
$$y = \frac{x^{p}(1-x)^{1-p}}{p^p(1-p)^{1-p}}$$

with $$0<p<1$$

It can be checked at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/es1znohisl

Comment: excellent! hopefully this was a fun problem to work on for you

Comment: May I ask about the context? What are you using it for?

Comment: a controls related task